# Style console.log output and run functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

After having a little snoop around the source code for http://pinterest.com, I noticed how they use the console to communicate with users (Appears to only work in Chrome).

[image]

Also, if I enter `joinUs()` on the console log, a function is run which directs me to a new page.

I attempted to run a function within the console log on my own website by declaring a function:

```
function testFunc(){
    console.log('Hello world!');
}
```

But if I try entering `testFunc()` on the console log, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: testFunc is not defined
```

Does anybody have any information on how to style the output of the console log, and how to run a function from within the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For styling, you could check https://github.com/adamschwartz/log
If you read through the code I'm sure you can figure out how it works.

As for having `testFunc` available, try explicitly assigning it to `window`, so do `window.testFunc = function () { console.log('Hello world!') };`. That should work.